# Induction question with minimal value of $k$

Tags: logic, induction

I have this question:

Given this set $A=\{n \in \mathbb{N} : 3^n >n^2 2^n\}$

Such that we can prove using induction on $n$ that $n \in A$ for all $k_0 \leq n$ . What is the minimal value of $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the logical operation: $n\in A \Rightarrow n+1 \in A$ is satisfied for all $n \geq k_0$?

What I've done is just take a random number and make it bigger or smaller accordingly, and so I found that $k_0 =13$ is the minimal value such that for each $n \leq k_0$ , $n+1 \in A$.

But, the answer gave me a wrong mark and the actual answer is $5$... Why? $5$ does not satisfy the condition of the set, nor $6$ ... What am I getting wrong here? Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: It seems that the actual question is not "what is the minimal $k_0\in A$", but rather "what is the minimal $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\in A\implies n+1\in A$ is satisfied for all $n\geq k_0$".

Comment: Yes, my bad i will edit the question, but still why is it 5 and not 13 ? Because 3^13 > 2^13 *13² and 14 , and 15 and so on ... @Balloon

Comment: I think we are getting wrong something. Is the expression in the definition of the set $A$ correct?

Comment: @Air Mike yes the definition of A is correct

Comment: And the minimal value in $A$ is 5? That doesn’t sound right

Comment: The question is the same tho, my final answer was 13 , however they say 5 is correct.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a property $P(n)$, depending of an integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that you would like to prove being true for all $n$ greater than some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$. One way of doing it is as you said by induction, namely you have to prove that the two following new properties (created from $P$) are true:

- $P(n_0)$,
- $\forall k\geq n_0,P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ (and let's call this property $Q(n_0)$, since it depends only of the integer $n_0$).

The fact is, the smallest integers such that $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$ are true are not necessarily the same! For example, in your question, the smallest one for which $P(n)=\,"n\in A"$ is true is $13$, as you found. But the question ask you to find the smallest $n$ for which $Q(n)=\,"\forall k\geq n,k\in A\implies k+1\in A"$ is true, which will likely be $5$.

Answer (score 0):

I must be making a math error somewhere.  The way that I interpret the question is as follows:

Suppose that $3^n > 2^n \times n^2.$
Then $\ln (1.5) > \frac{2 \ln (n)}{n}.$

Therefore, the question is really asking for the following:
Let $f(x) = \frac{2 \ln (x)}{x}.$ 
Find $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0, f'(x) < 0.$

Then $n$ will be the smallest postive integer $ > x_0.$

$f'(x) = \frac{2}{x^2} \;-\; \frac{2 \ln x}{x^2}.$ 
This is a key step.  If I have made an error here, **please advise.**

Thus $f'(x) \;=\; \frac{2}{x^2} \times (1 \;-\; \ln x).$ 
Thus $x_0 = e$ and $n = 3.$

I have no explanation for why the correct answer is supposed to be 5, instead of 3.  Either I have made a math error (which I can't find), the intended interpretation of the problem is similar but critically different from my interpretation, or the correct answer is 3 rather than 5.